# MutableList to HashMap in Kotlin

Tags: list, kotlin, hashmap

I want to convert the value of `MutableList` to `HashMap`. Can you help me with this? This is my code:

```
private fun getDestinationFund(destinationFund: List<DestinationFundEntity>) {
        val list = mutableListOf<FundsModel>()
        for (i in destinationFund) {
            list.add(
                FundsModel(
                    ljiId = i.ljiId,
                    name = i.productName,
                    mduPercent = i.percentage
                )
            )
        }

        convertListToMap(list)
}
```

```
private fun convertListToMap(list: MutableList<FundsModel>) {
   val map: HashMap<String?, FundsModel> = HashMap()

   // Need to convert "list" from params to "map" from "val"

   // So, the Live data get data from "map", not from "list"
   _currentFundsList.postValue(ArrayList(map.values))
}
```

Comment: What key should the resulting map have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed using this:

```
private fun convertListToMap(list: MutableList<FundsModel>) {
     val map: HashMap<String?, FundsModel> = HashMap()

     list.forEach {
         map[it.name] = it
     }

     _currentFundsList.postValue(ArrayList(map.values))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `List.map()` to transform your list into a list of `Pair`s, and then use `toMap()` on that list:

```kotlin
listOf(1,2,3,4)
  .map { it -> it to it * 2 }
  .toMap()

// produces: {1=2, 2=4, 3=6, 4=8}
```

Comment: You can replace this with: listOf(1,2,3,4).associateWith { it * 2 }